# Get entity type from ChangeTracker in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

At the time of calling `SaveChanges()` on my DBContext, I need to know which entities have been added, modified, or deleted. To do this, I have the following method:

```
private IDictionary<string, List<Type>> GetChangedEntityTypes()
{
    var changes = new Dictionary<string, List<Type>>();

    foreach (var state in new[] { EntityState.Added, EntityState.Modified, EntityState.Deleted })
    {
        var metadataOfAffectedTypes = ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Where(e => e.State == state)
            .Select(e => e.Metadata);

        var typesAffected = metadataOfAffectedTypes.Select(m => m.ClrType);
        changes.Add(state.ToString(), typesAffected.ToList());
    }
            
    return changes;
}
```

Which I call from an override of `SaveChanges()` like so:

```
var changedTypes = GetChangedEntityTypes();
var saveResult = base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

if (changedTypes.Any(e => e.Value.Any()))
{
    OnEntitiesChanged(new EntitiesChangedEventArgs(changedTypes));
}

return saveResult;
```

The problem I have is with the `ClrType` property on the entity metadata. Sometimes this is the actual type of the entity, other times it is not (in some cases it shows up as a `Dictionary<string, object>`). Is there a way to reliably get the type of an entity from the change tracker?

I am using the latest EF Core, and have `UseLazyLoadingProxies()` enabled in my startup file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

following approach works for me

```
Entry.Entity.GetType()
```

select `e => e.Entity.GetType()` instead of `e => e.Metadata`

note: it's not good for performance